# Scrolling to element with onscroll or similar event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the large page to be scrolled down to predefined element when I'm using the scrollbar or the mouse wheel while another element occupies the screen. In other words, I need the page to be scrolled to the certain element automatically when I'm just starting scrolling.

Say there are several DIVs, each occupy the whole viewport to make testing convenient. When **div_1** is visible I want the page to scroll to the **div_3** just by one click of a mouse wheel or a scrollbar.

I can easily do that by clicking on the ancore element but nothing works when I change *onclick* to *onscroll*.

```
document.getElementById("div_1").onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('div_3').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    }
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1993as28/), there is *onclick* instead of *onscroll* just to ensure the script is working.

What have I missed?

Comment: It would be duplicate if i wanted to scroll by click while I'm trying to scroll by scroll (yes, it is!)

Comment: I see, my bad, sorry

Comment: Do you want it to happen every time user scrolls, or only while scrolling above `div_1`?

Comment: This is a little tricky, because `scrollIntoView` triggers `scroll` and you want to trigger `scrollIntoView` in `scroll` event.

Comment: Only by scrolling over `div_1`. I would even say when `div_1` is displayed, as I could scroll with the mouse wheel over `div_1`, but not with the browser's scrollbar.

Comment: There are several other ways to scroll other than `scrollIntoView`. The problem is I can't find a way to scroll to certain element by using any event related to *scroll*. Clicking on **div_1** works perfectly but I need to scroll to another div immediately as the script detects the user has just started scrolling in its direction.

Comment: This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnsbes3z/) example allows to use the mouse wheel or the touch pad over **div_1** to scroll the page directly to **div_3**, but not the scroll bar. The scrollbar solution is still missing.

Comment: It doesn't work on chrome and scrolls only when you are on top of a page and not when `div_1` is in a viewport.

Comment: It is normal wnen `div_1` located at the top of the page and takes the whole viewport. As for Chrome this browser shouldn't be at all ) Anyway you are right, I have to make the page compatible with it also

Comment: What?? Chrome offers the biggest support for any css, js properties. But it doesn't matter :) Did you look at my solution? It works now the way you want.

Comment: Just noticed you've updated your solution, thanks! But it doesn't allow to scroll back to `div_1`

Comment: It does, I wrote you below the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function() {
  if ($("#div_1").isInViewport()) {
    smoothScroll();
  }
});

function smoothScroll() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#div_3").offset().top
  }, 1000);
}

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

```css
div#div_1 {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

div#div_2 {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

div#div_3 {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
```

**EDIT**

Well, I think I finally did it :) [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnsbes3z/3/)

```js
var scrolling = false;

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($("#div_1").isInViewport()) {
    smoothScroll();
  }
});

function smoothScroll() {
  if (!scrolling) {
   scrolling = true;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#div_3").offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {
      scrolling = false;
    });
  }
}

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

```css
div#div_1 {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

div#div_2 {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

div#div_3 {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
```

If you would like to change the moment when it happens (right now it happens when `div_1` is in a viewport) change the `$.fn.isInViewport` function.

For example if you want it to happen when top of `div_1` is visible return this `return elementTop > viewportTop;`

```js
var scrolling = false;

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($("#div_1").isInViewport()) {
    smoothScroll();
  }
});

function smoothScroll() {
  if (!scrolling) {
   scrolling = true;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#div_3").offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {
      scrolling = false;
    });
  }
}

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementTop > viewportTop;
};
```

```css
div#div_1 {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

div#div_2 {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

div#div_3 {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
```

Comment: Other than your example works by **onclick** instead of **onscroll** and several times larger than in initial question, it works perfectly! )))

Comment: @YKKY I don't understand. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I need the page to scroll to the element by any event related to **scroll**, but not to **click** or any other. When **div_1** shows on page and the scrolling is initiated, I need the page to scroll directly to **div_3**.

Comment: @YKKY It works that way. The click event was added by you in a fiddle, that's why i left it.

Comment: Can't force it to work this way using FireFox 56.0.2 and the **Run code sninnet** button.

Comment: Now it works, but only with the mouse wheel, not the scroll bar. While researching I've found I could use `window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {if (e.deltaY > 0) {document.getElementById('div_3').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});}});` for using the mouse wheel, but my example works only **after the second attempt** to scroll the wheel.

Comment: @YKKY You wrote *as I could scroll with the mouse wheel over div_1, but not with the browser's scrollbar*

Comment: The complete phrase was `I would even say when div_1 is displayed, as I could scroll with the mouse wheel over div_1, but not with the browser's scrollbar`.

Comment: @YKKY chek it now